# Array passes through ajax but received as string in php

Tags: php, jquery

The following is my jquery code:

```
 e_val = [];
 e_val = ['enroll','reject'];
 $.ajax({
                url: 'myurl.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    reason: 'insert',
                    eval: e_val
                },
                success: function (suc) {
                    row.remove();
                    alert(suc);
                }
       });
```

myurl.php:

```
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$eval = array();
if($reason == "insert"){
     $eval = $_POST['eval'];
     echo $eval[1];
}
```

And the alert I get is:

```
n
```

That's because n is at index value 1 in e_val[0].
Can I know why is my array converted to string in PHP page and I'm not able to access the array elements?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because every value sent in a request is sent as a string. You'll need to convert it manually from a string to an array in your PHP.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Assuming the values are form-urlencoded, then [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) should do it for you

Comment: use JSON as dataType and parseJSON in php

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried but it's not working

Comment: @Anandhunadesh I tried this too but still not getting expected output

Comment: are u getting the expected result in the echo statement?

Comment: You can parse anything from jQuery/JS into php and encode/decode on both endpoints. But it is common practice to use JSON for this. Read up on it. It's not hard. It's a nifty way to convert your data in a dataformat that's standardized, structured and transferable, then PUT or POST the json data onto php (by using an ajax request), and then use JSON-decoding functions in php to unfold it all... and wow... magically your array will become available. 
It's just a tip... it will require some read up. I won't rewrite your code.

Comment: Nopes same output

Comment: Your code works for me with no modifications. I get an alert with 'reject'.

Comment: How's that possible? I'm still getting wrong output. @Don'tPanic

Comment: Did you paste the exact code you're running into the question? JavaScript and PHP? If you typed it into the question, or excluded some parts, the problem may have gotten lost in translation.

Comment: Just changed the URL which I don't think should make much difference.

Comment: If you use your browser's developer tools to examine the AJAX request, what does it look like? Particularly the content type header and request body. (Add that info to your question if you can.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode() with The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
                   var  e_val = [];
                   var  e_val = ['enroll','reject'];
                    console.log(e_val);
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'test2.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        reason: 'insert',
                        eval: e_val
                    },
                    success: function (suc) {
                        alert(suc);
                    }
           });
          // alert("dddd");
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
 <?php
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];
    $eval = array();
    if($reason == "insert"){
         $eval = $_POST['eval'];
         echo implode(', ', $eval );
       //  echo "Dddd";
    }
      // echo "Dddd";
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting no output

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType as json not text. And you may also want to add headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }. Also eval is a keyword in JAVASCRIPT avoid using it.
Something like,

```
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'myurl.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    data: {
                        reason: 'insert',
                        e_val: e_val
                    },
                    success: function (suc) {
                        row.remove();
                        alert(suc);
                    }
           });
```